# upload binary file using python requests

Tags: python-requests, postman

I am uploading a file using requests library below is the code:

```
files = {'file': open(full_file_name, 'rb')}
headers = {"content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
final_resp = requests.put(loc, files=files, headers=headers)
```

The problem is some extra contents have been added to the file's start and end point.

The contents added to the start point is:

```
--b16010ae7646a031a5adc64ac0661e72
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1016064585-65769268.csv"
```

The contents added to the endpoint is:

`--b16010ae7646a031a5adc64ac0661e72--`

But when the same file is uploaded through the [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) these problems are not arising.

here is the screenshot of the postman [image].

The header of the postman is:

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Comment: Data is required, such as I see from the URL, you should attach your username, and etc. please show us the params page of postman

Answer (score 23):

it may because you use multipart/form to upload file.try use data like code below

```
data = open(localFilePath, 'rb').read()
headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/binary",
}
upload = requests.put(uploadUrl,data=data,headers=headers)
```

Comment: It worked for me, with "data" it adds nothing to the header/bottom file (in this case audio file).